# Proof of Accommodation for summer festivals

Tags: accommodation, festivals

What should the proof of accommodation be while applying for visa in Europe (Schengen visa) as I will be attending summer festivals (camp facility)?

Answer (score 2):

A ticket for the festival and a note stating that you intend to camp or maybe a printout of the festival website indicating that camping is available should be perfectly fine. Basically everything that shows you have a reasonable and plausible plan can count as supporting documentation. Your application would be much weaker without festival tickets obviously.

Comment: A Note from whom ?

Comment: @raman From yourself, simply stating “From day 1 to day 4, I will camp in this place in the Netherlands, from day 5-6, I will camp there in Germany, etc.“ The point is showing you though this through and you are not making this up to disguise your purpose.